# How do I get a DIV to follow a transform

Tags: javascript, html, css

Long story short, I'm trying to put text inside a box that is animated with javascript.

```js
var two = new Two({
  fullscreen: true,
  autostart: true
}).appendTo(document.body);
const card = two.makeRoundedRectangle(230/2, two.height/2, 230, 130, 10);



const div = document.createElement("div");           // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT STUFF
const text = document.createTextNode("This is text.");    //
div.appendChild(text);                    // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT STUFF

two.update(); // this needs to be here to add to the dom 

card._renderer.elem.style.cssText = 'position:relative;width:230px;height:130px;';    // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT STUFF
div.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;width:200px;height:200px;';           // 
card._renderer.elem.appendChild(div);                          // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT STUFF

two.bind('update', function (framNum)
{
 card.translation.x += 1
 if (card.translation.x > two.width - 230/2)
 {
 card.translation.x = 230/2
 }
 
}).play()
```

```html
<script src="https://two.js.org/third-party/two.js"></script>
```

here's what I've tried. I'm trying to put `document.createTextNode("This is text.");` inside a parent that is moving

**I was expecting the to see the text, or even a div with the inspector, but its not highlighting.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: im 3/3 for posts with 0 comments on this site, what is wrong with this post exactly?

Comment: You've created an html node inside your svg. This is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `two`'s text functionality instead of using DOM related functions. It appears that in this context, `two` renders to an SVG format, thus adding HTML tags won't work.

```js
var two = new Two({fullscreen: true, autostart: true}).appendTo(document.body);
const card = two.makeRoundedRectangle(230/2, two.height/2, 230, 130, 10);

var styles = { size: 24, family: 'Calibri' }; 
var text = new Two.Text("This is text.", 120, 100, styles);

var group = two.makeGroup(card, text);

two.update(); // this needs to be here to add to the dom 

card._renderer.elem.style.cssText = 'position:relative;width:230px;height:130px;';   

two.bind('update', function (framNum)
{
 group.translation.x += 1
 if (group.translation.x > two.width - 230/2)
 {
 group.translation.x = 230/2
 }
 
}).play()
```

```html
<script src="https://two.js.org/third-party/two.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sadly i cant make the text word wrap this way but I'll create multiple lines instead